# Print API response in "Test results" tab in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using Postman automate an API with Newman.But the response body of the API call is not showing in the newman.

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Response Body ", body] = true;
```

I have tried the above code,but even after successful API call the response is not printing in the "Test results" tab.

the output of above is showing as,

```
PASS [object Object]
```

Any suggestions to print the API  response will be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using the `cli` reporter with Newman, you could just add a `console.log(pm.response.json())` statement to the `Tests` tab.

That should print out the response body on the console during the Newman run.

If you wanted something to show you *all* the details of the Newman run in a separate report, you could also use a different reporter, like this HTML one ;)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift response! I have tried "console.log(pm.response.json())" but it doesn't show anything.Is there any other way to print the response in the "test results" tab or am i doing anything wrong.Can you please guide.